# Can there be an /n/ sound in the word cemetery?

Tags: pronunciation

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cemetery) provides following transcriptions:

- /ˈsɛ.mə.ˌtɹi/
- /ˈsɛ.mə.ˌtɛ.ɹi/
- /ˈsɪ.mə.ˌtɛ.ɪ/

However, in [the audio sample](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File%3AEn-us-cemetery.ogg), I personally hear a faint, but distinct /n/ sound before the /t/, as

- /ˈsɛ.mən.ˌtɛ.ɹi/.

I don't hear it in [the Macmillan pronunciation example](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/media/british/uk_pron/c/cem/cemet/cemetery_British_English_pronunciation.mp3).

Is this me hearing things that aren't there, a quirk of pronunciation of the Wikipedia contributor, or a phenomenon of this sound combination which produces an /n/ sound which can be barely heard?

Comment: You should not hear /n/ in ___cemetary___; if the Wikipedia sample has it, the sample should be replaced.

Comment: In English the normal rule for vowel nasalization is that vowels preceding nasal consonants (/m n ŋ/) become nasal themselves. I.e, [ˈsɛmətɛɹi] becomes [ˈsɛ̃mətɛɹi]. Quite often that results in the listener hearing the expected nasal consonant even when it's not pronounced. Now if the speaker keeps the velic flap open past the nasal continuant [m], that will nasalize the following [ə] to [ˈsɛ̃mə̃tɛɹi], which could produce an aural image -- a phantom nasal [n] before [t]: [ˈsɛ̃mə̃ntɛɹi]. In Indonesian, vowels are nasalized **after** nasals, not before, and this has led to lots of problems.

Comment: So, in other words, you only think you're hearing an *n* sound. But kudos for spelling 'cemetery' correctly. Lots of folks put an *a* in place of the third *e*.

Comment: @JohnLawler Basically, the velum is a bit like a lumbering walrus compared to the other nimble acrobatic articulators. It takes ages to get lower to enable nasal sounds (and so has to get going early in aniticipation) and it takes eons to go back up again afterwards--and will quite probably only do so if it has to. So in a word like *Anna* it will probably stay down for the entire word. In other words English vowels are commonly nasalised both before and after nasals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's true that vowels do often nasalize when preceding nasal consonants (how much depends on dialect), the audio sample provided on Wikipedia clearly nasalizes the vowel and articulates a slight 'n' before [t]. Most likely the native speaker has conflated 'cement' with 'cemetery'. It is a non-standard example, but it is also a fairly common feature of native speaker English to conflate words like this. In North American English, the standard pronunciation should be [ˈsɛ.mə.ˌtɛ.ɹi] in careful speech and [ˈsɛ.mə.ˌtɹi] in allegro speech.

Comment: From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cemetery?pronunciation&lang=en_us&dir=c&file=cemete01). There should be no 'n'.

Comment: I disagree. I listened several times to the entire recording as well as just the segments, and there is no /n/ phoneme to my ear.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> In English the normal rule for vowel nasalization is that vowels preceding nasal consonants (/m n ŋ/) become nasal themselves. I.e, [ˈsɛmətɛɹi] becomes [ˈsɛ̃mətɛɹi]. Quite often that results in the listener hearing the expected nasal consonant even when it's not pronounced. Now if the speaker keeps the velic flap open past the nasal continuant [m], that will nasalize the following [ə] to [ˈsɛ̃mə̃tɛɹi], which could produce an aural image -- a phantom nasal [n] before [t]: [ˈsɛ̃mə̃ntɛɹi]. In Indonesian, vowels are nasalized **after** nasals, not before, and this has led to lots of problems.